# Terraform ad-hoc output

Tags: terraform

Is it possible to ask Terraform to provide an ad-hoc output? Looking at documentation in:

- https://www.terraform.io/language/values/outputs
- https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/output

I need to add to the script an output definition like:

```
output "instance_ips" {
  value = aws_instance.web.*.public_ip
}
```

Then run `terraform apply`, finally `terraform output instance_ips`.

I frequently want to inspect a value, eg. when setting up dependent resources. I would like to be able to run something like:

```
terraform output -adhoc 'aws_instance.web.*.public_ip'
```

Comment: Please elaborate on the difference between "ad-hoc" and the current functionality. It would seem that what you provided in the question satisfies your requirements (other than the incorrect usage with the `output` command).

Comment: Currently: I need 3 steps (edit file, run two commands). What I want: single command without needing to edit file.

Comment: It sounds like what you may be asking for is data: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/instance; otherwise please elaborate on requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `terraform output` command and the `terraform console` command both derive their results from the most recent Terraform state snapshot, which is why you need to run `terraform apply` in order to create a new state snapshot containing the data you want to refer to.

If this output value is declared in the root module then Terraform should also include it as part of the `terraform plan` output, allowing you to see what value Terraform expects it to take after the plan is applied.

```
Changes to outputs:
  + instance_ips = [
    + "10.2.3.4",
  ]
```

However, Terraform can do this only for values that are either derived entirely from data you defined statically in the configuration *or* values that the provider is able to predict during the planning phase. The public IP address of an EC2 instance gets decided only as part of creating it, and so it's more likely in your case that you'll see something less informative:

```
Changes to outputs:
  + instance_ips = [
    + (known after apply),
  ]
```

The `(known after apply)` placeholder represents situations where a provider cannot predict a value until one of the planned changes has already completed. In that case, there's no way to see this value without running `terraform apply` first, because it's applying the change which actually decides the value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My infrastructure is already deployed and I only want to evaluate an expression I don't yet have in the output. It's nice that `terraform plan` will display the value - it's one step less - but I still need to edit a file to add that output and save it before.

Comment: Actually `terraform console` is exactly what I was looking for, I wasn't aware of this subcommand! It allows me to write any ad-hoc expression and get immediate answer!

Comment: Oh, great! In that case, just note that `terraform console` can only show the results of actions you already applied. But if you just want to inspect something that already exists, rather than inspect the result of an action that hasn't happened yet, then it's a useful command for doing that.